# Unsure how to run Javascript animation in steps. I now have it implemented as running through the whole animation at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm creating an animation to show how a pattern matching algorithm works. Right now I have the full animation running from start to end when the sort button is pressed.

I am trying to implement a 'forward step' button (and also a 'back step' button) which when pressed will compare the pattern at the first position and then will compare it at the second position when it is pressed again etc. I'm unsure how I could implement this if it is even possible.

```
function kmp(p,t){
var k=0, j=0, result;
var fail=[];
var next=[];
var shifts = 0, comparisons = 0;
var boxWidth = $('#text_array .panel').outerWidth(true);
var places;
var previousMove = 0;
var totalMoves = 0;

kmpSetup(p, fail, next);

    xx = setInterval(function () {
        if(t[j] == p[k]) {
            turnGreen('#p', k);
            for(n=0; n<k; n++) {
                turnGreen('#p', n);
            }
            turnGreenWhite('#t', j);
            k = k+1;
            j = j+1;
        } else if(k==0) {
            j++;
        } else {
            turnRed('#p', k);
            turnRed('#t', j);
            for (var m = 0; m < p.length; m++) {
                turnWhite('#p', m);
            }
            turnWhite('#t', j);

            var position = k;
            k = next[k];

            //calculating how many places to shift the pattern
            // depending on the value in the table
            if (k == -1) {
                places = position + 1;
                totalMoves+=places;
                animatePattern(boxWidth, totalMoves, result);
                k = k+1;
            } else {
                places = position - k;
                totalMoves+=places;
                animatePattern(boxWidth, totalMoves, result);
            }

            if(j>=t.length && k>=p.length) {
                clearInterval(xx);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

if(k>=p.length){
    result='match found';//match found
} else {
    result='match not found';//no match found
}
return result;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_c_moore/1x307qtj/20/)

Comment: this is related much to algorithm, rather than javascript and css animation. Well it's fairly complicated to dig into this in ***free time*** :)

Comment: They have CSS animations for this sort of stuff, you know...

Comment: @gyre. Would what I'm trying to do be easier if I animated using Css animations?